# Increase the width of the user input box using ipywidgets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipywidgets

I am trying to increase the width of the user input box generated by the `interact` function from `ipywidgets`.

My objective is that a user should be able to change the contents of the string using the interactive box, however I am unable to figure out how to do so.

```
import re
from ipywidgets import interact

x1 = """The Supreme Court, in the matter of, held that moratorium  mentioned in section 141 Chapter XVII of the Act. / उच्चतम न्यायालय ने 

Dwarkadhish Sakhar Karkhana Ltd. Vs. Pankaj Joshi and Anr. / द्वारकाधीश 
Kalpraj Dharamshi & Anr. Vs. Kotak Investment Advisors Ltd. & Anr. / कल्पराज""" 

# remove all non-english characters
x2 = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', x1)

def f(x):
    return x

w = interact(f, x=x2)
```

(Width of the image showing the output reduced for ease of viewing)

[image]

However I want the input box to be much larger so that the user can make a change anywhere in the string using the box itself and that value is stored.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is for a Python Jupyter notebook.
Insted of using `interact`, use `Textarea`:

```
import re
from ipywidgets import Layout, Textarea

x1 = """The Supreme Court, in the matter of, held that moratorium  mentioned in section 141 Chapter XVII of the Act. / उच्चतम न्यायालय ने 

Dwarkadhish Sakhar Karkhana Ltd. Vs. Pankaj Joshi and Anr. / द्वारकाधीश 
Kalpraj Dharamshi & Anr. Vs. Kotak Investment Advisors Ltd. & Anr. / कल्पराज""" 

# remove all non-english characters
x2 = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', x1)


w = Textarea(value=x2, layout=Layout(width='70%', height='100px'))

# Show widget
w

# Access widget value, even if you have changed the original text
w.value
```

Comment: Would you also know how to reset `TextArea` after the code is done executing? If yes, I have asked a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76682815/ipywidgets-clear-and-reset-textarea