# ipywidgets clear and reset TextArea

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, ipywidgets

After I add some text to `TextArea` and run some preprocessing on that text I would like to reset the TextArea widget so I can add new text to it.

For example:

```
q1 = Textarea(layout=Layout(width='70%', height='100px'))
q1 # opens a window and then I add text to it
```

[image]

```
q2 = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7f]',r'', q1.value)
# do some more preprocessing
q1.reset() # I am looking for something like this
```

After preprocessing is complete, I'd like to reset `q1` to a blank cell so it is ready to take in as input a completely new value.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign any value to the `TextArea` widget.

So the answer is really simple.

```
q1.value = ""

# Show that the text area is now empty.

q1
```

Comment: The answer was in front of me all along. Thank you so much!